# Trying access EnviromentObject inside func makeCoordinator()

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I'm trying to continuously calculate a distance(from: the_userLocation) where the fixed lat/long are entered in the ContentView.
I can do this once in a func within `struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {` but I wanted to do a continuous calculation. I thought I might be able to do this inside
`func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation)` inside
`class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate`

I have the EnvironmentObject defined in one file

```
import SwiftUI

final class AppData: ObservableObject { // Don't know why final
    @Published var cornerLatitude: String = ""
    @Published var cornerLongitude: String = ""
    @Published var corner: Int = 1
}
```

At the top of the MapView file I've included the EnvironmentObject

```
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var appData: AppData
    var map = MKMapView()
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    
    init() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
```

In the class MapViewCoordinator func mapView if I uncomment the `let cornerLat =` and `let cornerLon =` lines I get the errors

`Instance member 'appData' of type 'MapView' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'MapView.MapViewCoordinator'`

I've tried other 'combinations' of code with similar results.

```
        let map: MKMapView
        
        init(map:MKMapView) {
            self.map = map
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
            let location = map.userLocation
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 500, longitudinalMeters: 500)
            map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

//            let cornerLat = Double(appData.cornerLatitude) ?? 0.0
//            let cornerLon = Double(appData.cornerLongitude) ?? 0.0

        }
    }
```

Any thoughts/suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand provided code then you can do the following (because AppData is a reference type)

Scratchy (not tested, just idea)

```
class MapViewCoordinator {

    let map: MKMapView
    let appData: AppData    // here !!
    
    init(map:MKMapView, appData: AppData) {
        self.map = map
        self.appData = appData        // << here !!
    }

    // ... use where needed as own property
```

and create in

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var appData: AppData
    var map = MKMapView()

    ...

    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
        MapViewCoordinator(map: map, appData: appData)   // << inject !!
    }
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I guess I was expecting the @EnvironmentObject to do all the work. However, I was already passing appData as a 'parameter' from the ContentView to func in MapView.